# Problem with getline() function when reading character array

Tags: c++

In my I am reading two character arrays ch1[5] and ch2[10].
Problem is when I enter ch1 more than 5 characters then I can't able to enter ch2. ch2 takes newline Character automatically. To ignore newline character I used cin.ignore() function but still it's not working.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstring>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        char ch1[5],ch2[10];
        cout<<"String Comparision :\n";
        cout<<" Enter strings 1 : ";
        cin.getline(ch1,5);
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Enter strings 2 : ";
        cin.getline(ch2,10);
        cout<<"Compairing... \n";
        if(strcmp(ch1,ch2))
             cout<<"Two Strings are Same";
        else cout<<"Two Strings are not Same";

        return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Why not use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Comment: Your logic is wrong for the `strcmp` conditional. `strcmp` returns 0 (false) if they're the same. Another reason to use the easier std::string

Comment: [ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) with no parameters only ignores 1 character

Comment: @MikeCAT because I want to study character Arrays

Answer (score 1):

If you enter more than 4 characters in `cin.getline(ch1,5);`, [`failbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) will be set on the stream. This prevents reading the stream afterwards - unless you first call [`cin.clear();`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear).

Note: `cin.ignore()` does not ignore the newline in your case.  `cin.getline` will already extract and discard the newline, so your `cin.ignore()` will instead remove the first character in the next line the user enters. What you could do is something like this:

```
#include <limits>

//...

cout<<" Enter strings 1 : ";
if(not cin.getline(ch1, 5)) {  // check if reading didn't work properly
   if(cin.eof()) return 1;     // cin was closed, exit

   cin.clear();                // clear failbit

   // ignore the rest of the long line
   cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
cout<<"Enter strings 2 : ";
//...
```

Note 2: You've got a bug in the `strcmp` logic. `std::strcmp` returns `0` if the C strings are equal.